# Discord.js Bots // Welcome function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I was trying to code my bot to execute different welcome messages if a player joins the server. The bot is not stating any issue in the code but every time someone joins, nothing happens, it just appears in the logs. Any clues?

```js
module.exports = (client) => {
 const channelId = '766761508427530250'; // welcome channel

 client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
  console.log(member);

  const welcomes = [
   `The member <@${member.id}> is joining us, welcome to ${member.guild}!`,
   `Say hello to <@${member.id}> Welcome to ${member.guild}!`,
   `Cheers, ${member}, welcome to the server!`,
   `I am smelling newcomers! Welcome, ${member} to ${member.guild}!`,
  ];

  const message = `${
   welcomes[Math.floor(Math.random() * welcomes.length)]
  } Please read the ${member.guild.channels.cache.get(
   '766731745960919052'
  )} and click on verify to gain full access to the server.`;

  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId);
  channel.send(message);
 });
};
```

Comment: Please stop marking your js questions with the java label.

Comment: Could you add more `console.log()` checkpoints to see where exactly the script stops being executed?

Answer (score 0):

Theres a few errors in your code so I'll just try to fix them for you. This version should definitely work anyways.

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  console.log(member);

  const welcomes = [
   `The member ${member} is joining us, welcome to ${member.guild}!`,
   `Say hello to ${member.id} Welcome to ${member.guild}!`,
   `Cheers, ${member}, welcome to the server!`,
   `I am smelling newcomers! Welcome, ${member} to ${member.guild}!`
  ];

  const message = `${welcomes[~~(Math.random() * welcomes.length)]} Please read the <#766731745960919052> and click on verify to gain full access to the server.`;

  const channelId = '766761508427530250'; // welcome channel
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(chan => chan.id === `${channelId}`);
  channel.send(message);
 });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I went through it myself and found the problems, still much appreciated!